# I can't loop vertically using v-for i'm stack

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a small project using VueJS, I try to loop over `body variable`  but I don't see the names between `<td></td>`

**this my code :**

```
<tr v-for="(row, i) in [body]" :key="`row-${i}`">
    <td v-for="(field, j) in mappedFields" :key="`mfield-${j}`">
         {{row[field]}} -
    </td>
</tr>
```

**This is my body variable :**

```
{
    name: ["amine", "bill"],
    adress: ["montreal", "new york"]
    company: ["apple", "microsoft"]
    email: ["my@gmail.com", "john@microsoft.com"]
    phone: [5497821445449, 559485556555]
}
```

**The result I get :**

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Comment: try {{row.name[field]}}

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada  doesnt fix what im looking for :) nice try ;)

Comment: `[body]` is an array with one value `{name: [...}`. You have one row with 5 columns. Each  cell contains an array. You should rethink your structure. You need something like `body = [{name: ...}, {name: ...}]`

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada  i want to loop vertically

Comment: @jabaa what should i do please

Answer (score 2):

`[body]` is an array with one value `{name: [...}`. You have one row with 5 columns. Each  cell contains an array. You should rethink your structure. You need something like `body = [{name: ...}, {name: ...}]`

In your example body  should be:

```
[{
    name: "amine",
    adress: "montreal",
    company: "apple",
    email: "my@gmail.com",
    phone: 5497821445449
},{
    name: "bill",
    adress: "new york",
    company: "microsoft",
    email: "john@microsoft.com",
    phone: 559485556555
}]
```

and

```
<tr v-for="(row, i) in [body]" :key="`row-${i}`">
```

should be

```
<tr v-for="(row, i) in body" :key="`row-${i}`">
```

Here is a running example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-mnooss?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 2):

refactor body variable to more structured one
for example

```
 [
   { 
      name: 'amine',
      address: 'montreal',
      company: 'apple',
      email: 'my@gmail.com',
      phone: 5497821445449
   },
   { 
      name: 'bill',
      address: 'new york',
      company: 'apple',
      email: 'john@microsoft.com',
      phone: 5497821445449
   },
 ]
```

move variable in computed if you wish

Answer (score 0):

If you've not the possibility to change the object structure, try to use anther computed property that refactors that object to an array :

```
data(){
  return{
   body:{
    name: ["amine", "bill"],
    adress: ["montreal", "new york"]
    company: ["apple", "microsoft"]
    email: ["my@gmail.com", "john@microsoft.com"]
    phone: [5497821445449, 559485556555]
   }
 }
},
computed:{
  rows(){
   let _rows=[];
   let vals=Object.values(this.body);
    for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
       _rows[i]=vals.map(v=>v[i])
     }
   return _rows;

 }

}
```

in template :

```
<tr v-for="(row, i) in rows" :key="`row-${i}`">
    <td v-for="(cell,j) in row" :key="`mfield-${j}`">
         {{cell}} -
    </td>
</tr>
```