# show object keys in select options

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a small project using, VueJs and Django

i have a JSON response :

```
[{
    'name': "amine",
    'adress': "montreal",
    'company': "apple",
    'email': "my@gmail.com",
    'phone': '5497821445449'
},{
    'name': "bill",
    'adress': "new york",
    'company': "microsoft",
    'email': "john@microsoft.com",
    'phone': '559485556555'
}]
```

i would like to show the keys `( name, adress, company, email, phone )` between `<option></option>`

i did :

```
<option v-for="(field, i) in header" :key="i">{{ field }}</option>
```

but it doesn't work

expected result

```
<option>name</option>
<option>adress</option>
<option>company</option>
<option>email</option>
<option>phone</option>
```

Comment: Please take a look at our [tour] and [How do I ask a **good** question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), a [mre] and expected output are the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a computed property that returns the object keys :

```
computer:{
  options(){
     const [firstItem]=this.body;
     return Object.keys(firstItem)
  }

}
```

template :

```
 <option v-for="(field, i) in options" :key="i">{{ field }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `list[0]` to get the first object from `list` array
2. `v-for="(value, name) in list[0]"` Loop through the object
3. Set value: `:value="name"`
4. Set content: `{{ name }}`

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const App = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    template: (`
        <div>
            <select>
                <option v-for="(value, name) in list[0]" :value="name"">{{ name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    `),
    data: function () {
        return {
            list: [
                {
                    'name': "amine",
                    'adress': "montreal",
                    'company': "apple",
                    'email': "my@gmail.com",
                    'phone': '5497821445449'
                },
                {
                    'name': "bill",
                    'adress': "new york",
                    'company': "microsoft",
                    'email': "john@microsoft.com",
                    'phone': '559485556555'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Will produce a HTML structure like:

```html
<select>
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="adress">adress</option>
    <option value="company">company</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="phone">phone</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i must have only one <select> </select> not twice

Comment: Only 1 select with 5 options? Could you maybe add desired html to the OP?

Comment: yes exactly Only one 1 select with 5 option man please, help its about 48 hours im looking for the solution

Comment: thank you can you please see the expected result here  : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796327/i-cant-loop-vertically-using-v-for-im-stack/66797272#66797272

Comment: Linking your old question doesn't help. Please elaborate THIS question!